# Free action of a discrete group gives a covering space

Tags: general-topology, covering-spaces

I'd like to find a short proof of the following seemingly basic fact. Suppose a discrete group $G$ acts freely on a manifold $X$ with the quotient $X/G$ being compact. Then $X$ is a covering space of $X/G$ with covering map given by the quotient map $p: X\rightarrow X/G$.

This appears on the second page of Atiyah's paper "Elliptic operators, discrete groups, and von Neumann algebras." http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/atiyah_elld.pdf

Thanks.

Comment: If we assume that $G$ acts properly as well then you can find an easy proof in Tammao Tom Dieck's book *Transformation groups*

Comment: Perhaps one can show the action is proper using that $X/G$ is compact?

Comment: What if $\mathbb{Z}$ acts on $S^1$ via irrational rotations? The quotient is compact but not Hausdorff.

Comment: Indeed this seems to be a counter-example!